# Is there a way to post data from a html form into a Lotus Notes database

Tags: ajax, post, xpages, lotus-domino

In a project I'm working on, I extract data from a Lotus Notes database and save this as a JSON file for use in a web application.

Now, I need to know if there is some way for me to reverse this - use Ajax POST to send data from my web app and have it inserted into the Lotus database. I've done some browsing, but I'm not sure if maybe I'm looking up the wrong things, because I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You can use "classic" Domino and create an agent that you post your data to, or you can use XPages and create an XPage that you post your data to.

I have blogged about [a HTTP request consumer written in XPages](http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2010/12/http-request-consumer-in-xpages.html),  and Chris Toohey has blogged about [a HTTP request consumer written as a Lotusscript agent](http://www.dominoguru.com/pages/simple_http_request_consumer_traditional.html).

Answer (score 5):

Or use Domino Data Service. Very powerful. More detail
http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/domino/8.5.3/doc/designer_up1/en_us/DominoDataService.html

**Update:** The data service is just one of the REST APIs available with Domino.  Collectively, the APIs are called Domino Access Services.  Here a link to the latest documentation:  [IBM Domino Access Services 9.0.1](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Domino%20Access%20Services%209.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=IBM_Domino_Access_Services_overview_das901&content=apicontent).  The data service has been available since Domino 8.5.3 UP1.  The 9.0.1 documentation includes a few newer features, but it can still be used for the 8.5.3 UP1 and 9.0 APIs.